# asp.NET Dynamic Data Site and asp.NET MVC-2 site together

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, dynamic-data

I have created firstly **ASP.NET MVC 2**. and write more functionality. After I create **asp.NET Dynamic Data Site**.

now, when I click on run button in Visual Studio, mvc app. opened in browser as http://localhost:50062. and asp.NET Dynamic Data Site as http://localhost:58395/cms/.

but i want to merge this app. in one. can I use asp.NET Dynamic Data Site and asp.NET MVC-2 at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this Scott Hanselman article:

**Plug-In Hybrids: ASP.NET WebForms and ASP.MVC and ASP.NET Dynamic Data Side By Side** http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlugInHybridsASPNETWebFormsAndASPMVCAndASPNETDynamicDataSideBySide.aspx